# Is this question acceptable? If not, how can I rephrase it to make it acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is the following a valid question? If not, why not, and how can I improve it to make it acceptable?

> - I want to bring order to the books on my Kindle.
> - Kindle offers   "collections", which are like folders/directories.
> - Collections are  only available when you register.
> - I don't want to   register the   device.
>
> Is there any gratis Windows app which will help me?
>
> I am also open installing a Linux distro, if there is a reliable "how to" to guide me, so long as it is then fairly easy to structure my books.
>
> If it matters any, I use Calibre to transfer books to my device, although I could change if there were a compelling reason.

Is that acceptable? The Windows bit is a little vague, simply because I am not aware of any possible Windows solution.

I believe that Linux distros are on topic, though.

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's valid as I'm not a meta-regular, but I can perhaps give some tips on how I'd like to see it improved as a potential answerer.

Your bullet list is not quite a check list for the things you want of the software, but a bulleted description of your context. I'd recommend rewriting it as a regular piece of proze, e.g.:

> I want to bring order to the books on my Kindle. Kindle offers "collections", which are like folders/directories, but Collections are only available when you register, and I don't want to register the device.

From that context I can get 2 requirements for the replacement app you're looking for:

> So, to summarize, I'm looking for software that:
>
> 1. Must have: Doesn't require me to register my Kindle.
> 2. Must have: Helps me orginize my books on my Kindle.

Then there's these three extra requirements:

> 3. Must have: Runs on Windows preferably, but I'd try installing a Linux distro just for this if it is beginner-friendly to do so.
> 4. Must have: Gratis.
> 5. Nice to have: Compatible with using Calibre to transfer books to my device. (I'm happy to switch if there's a good reason.)

Mainly point 2 is a bit vague. You could help answerers by telling them what your detailed requirements would be, possibly ordered by priority or in [MoSCoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_method) fashion. Some things that come to mind:

- What do you expect of the interface? Is the UX important or can you deal with a learning curve? Does it need to be aestathically pleasing?
- Do you want a *lightweight* app or a power tool with many features (and if so: what power features would you like? mass-renames? regex-based searches? powerful drag-and-drop? a command-line tool to go along?).
- Do you know any (features from) comparable apps (e.g. a music-library-app, or an old version of the app, or an app for other types of e-readers) that you like? Tell us about them.
- What kind of "*Order*" are you looking to bring to your collection? Just a hierarchical folder-like structure? Or do you want tagging features? Special categorization features? Browse by author, isbn language or number, etc?

Again, I'm no meta-regular, so others may need to chip in, but I think you have a valid question at its core, but it wouldn't hurt to add some details.